# extract information from Joomla Portal (Joomla module)

Tags: php, joomla

I have a PHP app, and I want some of the latest data to be extracted and display on a Joomla portal. I just couldn't figure out, can I return an XML document or what is the best way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return these information in XML format and for example: [snJxml2xslt2joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/site-management-tools/6558?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo0OiJ4c2x0Ijt9)
You can also return these information in RSS format and use the standard RSS feed module to show it in Joomla!

Or do you want to show some information FROM the Joomla site on an other site?

Comment: I have a separate membership system on one hosting and a Joomla portal on another hosting. I want to extract information from the membership system and displayed it on Joomla portal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to extract in XML format and display on my Joomla Portal.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you want to display the information within a module in Joomla. If that's the case, then you can write your own database connection code (or override Joomla's) and pull the data directly out of the PHP application's database (assuming it's in a database).

If it's not, then there are several RSS/XML parsers within Joomla that will work such as the XML-RPC.

Comment: I don't have much control on Joomla side, can I write something from my membership system and produce a URL or something, so that ppl from Joomla can easily get it and displayed??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run a cron job to pull a data on regular basis and insert it into your local joomla portal DB. This way you have greater control over what you'd want to do with the data.

This might not be the best solution though. It also greatly depends on the kind of information you'd want to bring across. XML could be a bit more involved in terms of getting the structure right and so on.

Comment: cron job would be much work I think, because I just want to display a few lines of latest feeds only.